# UISearchBar extends behind UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Why does this UISearchBar extend it's background up and behind the navigation bar? It does it only on this one view controller in my project with 38 view controllers. But the settings in this view controller are not special in comparison with all the others.

[image]

Why I ask is because this creates a problem on iOS 11. The searchbar is then not centered anymore. I have already re-created the whole storyboard, but the effect still happens again. So I assume it is some code which I do in the view controller. But I have no idea what could cause this. Thanks.

Edit: as requested, here the auto-layout constraints:

[image]

[image]

All constants are 0, except the height of course.

Comment: Please show what autolayout constraints you have provided between the search bar and navigation bar.

Comment: Here you are, thanks.

Comment: Can you please expand the constraint for "Align top to: Safe Area"

Comment: I have added it. As you can see - nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the problem. There was some age-old code in this view controller:

```
extension MyViewController : UINavigationBarDelegate {
    func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
        return UIBarPosition.topAttached
    }
}
```

Removing this code fixed everything.

Comment: Thanks! Worth noting that this is a behavior change between iOS 10 and 11.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I resolved it by putting the search bar into a UIView and then applied the constraint on UIView.

Comment: No, this was not the problem. I have found the answer and posted it. Nevertheless thanks.